# access imported tag from array in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I would like to access a tag that is imported into an array.

`{files[1]}` is not displaying anything.
The only way to display the imported tag is to use the normal declaration: `<FileOne/>`

This is what I tried to do:

```js
const FileOne = (
  () => {
    return 
      <div>FileOne</div> 
    )
  }
)

export default FileOne;
```

```js
import FileOne from "./Files/FileOne";
import FileTwo from "./Files/FileTwo";

const files = [FileOne, FileTwo];

export default function FilesPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FileOne/> {/* works */}
      {files[1]} {/* doesn't work */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work if you define your array to have JSX elements and not the function:

```
const files = [<FileOne/>, <FileTwo/>]

export default function FilesPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      {files[0]}
      {files[1]}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Typo

First of, you have an incorrect *(* in your declaration of `FileOne`. It should be this:

```
const FileOne = (
  () => {
    return 
      <div>FileOne</div> 
  }
)
```

and even then I am not sure if that is really what you want. Shouldn't it be more like this:

```
const FileOne = () => {
  return <div>FileOne</div>;
};
```

### Solution

As the *variables* in your `files` array are functions, you have to call them. So it should be like this:

```
export default function FilesPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FileOne/> {/* works */}
      {files[1]()} {/* works now */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/vYpbqgx?editors=1010) for a working demo.